# Example of dual of vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: vectors, dual-spaces

Assuming the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $e_1, e_2, e_3$ and the corresponding dual basis vectors are $\theta^1, \theta^2, \theta^3$ (by the standard identification $\theta^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$).

What is the dual of $2e_1$? My guess would be $2\theta^1$, however, I'm unsure of whether the coefficient $2$ would become $\frac{1}{2}$ under the isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to its dual space.

Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:** I've realised I am referring to the outcome of applying a musical isomorphism (given all the necessary structure of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold (i.e. metric) required). In this case, the isomorphism is conventionally known as its **flat**, $$\flat:TM\to T^*M$$
where $M=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is no such thing as the dual of a single vector. Each (ordered) basis has a dual (ordered) basis. So if you tell us what the other two elements of of the basis that begins $\{2e_1,\dots\}$ [there are lots!] then we can tell you.

Comment: I thought I had already specified the ordered dual basis at the beginning of the question?

Comment: You specified a basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and its dual basis $\{\theta^1,\theta^2,\theta^3\}$. That's all.

Comment: I think I see where my confusion lies. I assumed the "dual of a vector" $v\in V$ would be defined as $w=f(v)$ where $f:V\to V^*$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Indeed, there is not a *natural* isomorphism between $V $ and $V^*$.

Comment: Yes. I think the point is that each basis and its dual sets up such an isomorphism, but it's not "natural" [in the technical sense], there's no way of doing it without choosing bases. - that is, if we are just talking about the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$; if we are talking about the standard inner product space on $\mathbb{R}^3$ then there is a way to do it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not *a dual linear form* of a vector.

You can complement $2 e_1$ into a basis $\{2 e_1, f_2, f_3\}$. Providing that $f_2,f_3$ belong to the subspace spanned by $\{e_2,e_3\}$, the dual basis will then be $\{1/2 \theta_1, f_2^*, f_3^*\}$.

However again, there is not a notion of the dual of a single vector.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on choosing $f_2,f_3$ in the span of $e_2,e_3$?

Comment: I think I should rephrase the question and ask about the corresponding element in the dual space under an isomorphism between V and V*, where V is a vector space. After thinking a bit more, I suspect there may be multiple isomorhisms that could be constructed between V and its dual V*. However, under the presence of the metric there is already an isomorphism defined..?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for reading it carefully. You’re right. I’ll update my answer accordingly.